# In Farflung, how do the Last of Their Kind counsel points work?

Tags: powered-by-the-apocalypse, moves, farflung

The Powered by the Apocalypse game *Farflung* from Sanguine Productions makes use of “points in time”, organised into two pools: History (Hx) and Future (Fx). In general, Fx is “anted up” as a requirement or power up for a character’s special moves that represent their unique powers and abilities, or to “push” actions by granting a re-roll. After being anted, those points are moved to the Hx pool (or on a failed roll, usually back into Fx). The main way to regain Fx is for another player to use the Inspiration move, leaning on a connection to another player, who antes up their Hx to provide a bonus to the inspired character and then shifted those points into Fx. This means you use your own points until they run out, and get them back by helping someone else out when it’s their time to shine.

Some playbooks can also “set aside” points, usually from Fx, into a special pool used just by that playbook; for example, the time travelling “Clockworker” can accrue a pool of “paradox” which powers their abilities to meddle with time. Most of these are straightforward in how they’re used, but a key part of the **Counsel** move for the “Last of Their Kind” playbook seems to be garbled on the character sheet.

The setup and roll for the move makes perfect sense: you ante up some Fx points, using the number anted as the bonus for the roll, and if successful sets 1 or more of these points in front of another player as “counsel”. But the rules for how the counsel points are used don’t make sense:

> At any time, the player may ask if what they’re about to do is in line with their counsel. If you say yes, they may move 1 point of your counsel to your Hx pool to their own Fx pool.

It seems part of that last sentence is wrong or missing, and it’s unclear how this should resolve.

We’ve guessed that they move your counsel point to your Hx pool, but get to use it as if it was an Fx point of their own. This lets them ante one more Fx point than they otherwise could on whatever move they’re about to make.

Other interpretations we can come up with involve adding +1 to their next move (which seems inferior to the standard Inspiration move everyone gets), or moving points from the counselling player’s pool to the counselled player’s indefinitely. That latter one seems especially unlikely since in the rest of the game pool points are only moved between a single player’s pools. (Everyone starts with 5 points between Hx and Fx, with the split specified by the playbook.)

The developer’s website has no errata, and I’ve not found anything online elsewhere either. So I’m asking here: does anyone know how the counselled player is supposed to use these points?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Hx and Fx points do move between players occasionally.

> At the end of each session of play, the player will get to rearrange all their points in time. That time will be when you can empty out these pools and put your points back into circulation. Some characters, like the Hero of the Universe, can give their points to other characters; the end-of-session reset is when everyone gets their points back.
>
> -- "Your Points In Time", *Farflung* p. 13

The Hero of the Universe moves their **heroics** into someone else's Fx through an inspiring speech. The Ship can ante their **cargo** instead of Fx for someone to supply with and as such their **cargo** winds up in that character's Hx. The Simulacrum can ask you to please state the nature of the medical emergency and leave a point of their time ante to treat you on your **scars**.

Or, less interpersonally, the Eternal and the Techie see points accumulate in **eternal** and **scraps** to empower them in certain ways, but with no way out other than the session reset.

##### In this case *counsel* should probably move to your target's Fx.

The conditions actually seem very similar to the ones under which the Hero of the Universe can send their **heroics** to someone's Fx: "if their next move is in the spirit of your urge" (p. 65). Absent any word from the original developers (and really, you should probably contact them about this) it seems reasonable for a move with the tagline "as your time ends, theirs begins" to work the same way.

Comment: This is a great answer, thank you - not played with a Hero and missed that others can give points to other players! As for asking the developers, the friend who introduced me to the game tried contacting them anbout errata, but got basically a “there isn’t any” response.

Comment: I’ve gone ahead and accepted this answer, as I don’t expect to see a better one!

Comment: Though a follow up question: given the “does this match your counsel” question, do you think if the answer is no then the point is returned to the Last of Their Kind’s Hx?

Comment: @GuybrushMcKenzie If we're going by analogy to heroics, counsel will just stay there until it's used. This is where the developer might help - I can see how there might also be some kind of return mechanism, but there's just not enough there to reconstruct it. But I guess that help's never coming.